# "Array" Appearing Before JSON Ouput

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I don't understand why there is an extra word ARRAY infront of the JSON string.

Heres the output of JSON String:

```
Array{"Users":[{"UserID":"1","FirstName":"lalawee","Email":"12345","Password":null},{"UserID":"2","FirstName":"shadowblade721","Email":"12345","Password":null},{"UserID":"3","FirstName":"dingdang","Email":"12345","Password":null},{"UserID":"4","FirstName":"solidsnake0328","Email":"12345","Password":null}],"success":1}
```

This is the PHP file:

```
<?php
/*
* Following code will list all the Users
*/
// array for JSON response
$response = array();
// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
// get all Users from Users table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users") or die(mysql_error());
// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// Users node
$response["Users"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $user[] = array();
    $user["UserID"] = $row["UserID"];
    $user["FirstName"] = $row["FirstName"];
    $user["Email"] = $row["Email"];
    $user["Password"] = $row["Password"];

    // push single User into final response array
    array_push($response["Users"], $user);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;
echo $response;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
else {
// no Users found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No Users found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Please try using a helpful non-screaming title for your thread. By tagging your question with PHP, we know you need help with PHP. If you have an informative title, you might get more answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove

```
echo $response;
```

which is printing the word Array. If you try to echo the array, it will display the word 'Array' rather than printing the content of an array itself. Use print_r() function to display the content of an array.

```
print_r($response);
```

Answer (score 2):

With the exception of classes that use the `__to_string` magic method, `echo` and `print` will only output the string interpretation of a variable's value.  Number types (integers and floats), strings, and (I think) booleans have a straightforward string representation. Any other variable (arrays, objects, resources) will either output nothing, their variable type, or throw a fatal error.

For arrays and objects, `print_r()` will go through each member/property and attempt to convert it to a string (print_r being shorthand for print_recursive).  So `print_r($response)` will give you the full array.

Bear in mind that generally the full array is only useful to output for debugging. Passing a php string version of an array to javascript is likely to be useless.