# PHP JSON response writes 'Array' before JSON output

Tags: php, json

I am having the same problem as outlined in this Question:
["Array" Appearing Before JSON Ouput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707198/array-appearing-before-json-ouput)

The output from PHP shows the word 'Array' before the JSON:

```
Array[{"item":{"ID":"1","idUser":"1",.......}}]
```

I have tried using `echo(..)` and `print_r(..)`, but both show the word 'Array'.

```
    public function render($content) {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $json = json_encode($content);        
        echo($json);  // also tried print_r($json)
        return true;
    }
```

The variable `$json` on the PHP side looks fine - i.e. not `Array[{"item":{"ID":"....` just  `[{"item":{"ID":"...`

Can anyone enlighten me?!

Comment: `json_encode()` will not do what you're saying. There will be an `echo` or a `print` somewhere else in your program that is doing this. Try taking the `json_encode()` out completely; the `Array` will remain.

Comment: what is it printing if you try `var_dump($content);`?

Comment: var_dump($content) gives Array<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>....

Comment: print_r($content) gives ArrayArray
(
    [0] => Array
        (

Comment: whatever I try, I get the 'Array' at the beginning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry but yes you have an other output elsewhere in your code.

However, to try to resolve your issue, you can clean the precedent output with the [`ob_end_clean`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php) function like this:

```
public function render($content) {

   ob_end_clean();

   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   $json = json_encode($content);        
   echo $json;  // also tried print_r($json)
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Nice one! You are right, there was another echo buried in the code, which I missed earlier. However, that's a great function to know about--- many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove echo, just return the json variable.
i.e. return $json;

Comment: How do I then send this back to the client as an http response?

Comment: What is the rest of the code? Are you using a framework? Return the data to the view